# "Table or view does not exist" error when connecting to oracle through jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, tns

I have a user RXXS with its own tablespace RXXS in Oracle DB 11g. Here is the sql for it:

```
-- USER SQL
ALTER USER "RXXS" 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE "RXXS"
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
ACCOUNT UNLOCK ;

-- ROLES
ALTER USER "RXXS" DEFAULT ROLE "RESOURCE","CONNECT";

-- QUOTAS
ALTER USER "RXXS" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON RXXS;
```

When I connect with this user to DB through Oracle SQL Developer (connection details: `rxxs@//127.0.0.1:1521/xe`), everything looks just fine. I can do selects and updates.

But when I am trying to connect (`jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe user: rxxs`) with this user through TNSListener (from my java ee app; running in jboss 4.0) and make a select, I have got the `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`.

The same select from Oracle SQL Developer runs successfully.

Can somebody help me with it please?

Comment: What is the exact query you execute?

Comment: select this_.ROWGUID as ROWGUID66_0_, this_.CUSTOMER_CODE as CUSTOMER2_66_0_ from RXXС_CUSTOMER this_ order by this_.ROWGUID asc

Comment: give out some code on how you connect to your db

Comment: The issue was resolved. Turned out that project spring-db config is forcing to change the default schema for user to some hardcoded one, that why tables were not found. Thanks everyone for interest.